# How to make an ordered list of boolean array permutations with a given number of trues

Tags: optimization, rust, combinations

Is there an efficient method to generate all possible arrays of booleans with a given number of "true" values?

Right now I'm incrementing a number and checking if its binary representation has the given number of 1s (and if so, adding that array). But this becomes extremely slow for larger givens.

This is the kind of input-output that I'm looking for:

```
(length: 4, trues: 2) -> [[1,1,0,0],[1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0],[1,0,0,1],[0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,1]]
```

The trouble is doing it in less than O(2^N), and so that they're ordered as the little endian binary representations would be.

If it helps the length would be a fixed number at compile time (currently it's 64). I wrote it as an input because I might have to increase it to 128, but it won't vary during runtime.

Comment: If the number of trues is configurable at run time, you'll need to generate vectors, not arrays.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks, I'm aware that the function would generate an Vec<[bool]> (currently a Vec<[bool;64]>), but didn't specify in the pseudocode for simplicity. I edited the question to clarify which input varies at runtime.

Comment: Did you try the `permutations()` or `combinations()` from the itertools crate? I tried [something like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=32594bf015f1da1b9c4e228ac620f386), but that returned many more permutations than your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a recursive solution to this problem.

```rust
fn solution(length: u32, trues: u32) -> Vec<Vec<bool>>;
```

How do we formulate this function recursively? Let's think about the last element of the output arrays. If that last element is `false`, then the amount of `true` elements in the `0..length-1` elements must be `trues`. If that last element is `true`, then the amount of `true` elements in the `0..length-1` elements must be `trues-1`.

So we can just answer the problem for `(length-1, trues)` and then extend them all with `false`, and answer the problem for `(length-1, trues-1)` and extend them all with `true`, and then we can combine the result (putting the ends-with-`true` case first for little endian ordering). Adding in some base cases, we get the following code:

```rust
fn solution(length: u32, trues: u32) -> Vec<Vec<bool>> {
    if trues > length {
        // no candidate arrays exist
        return vec![];
    }
    if length == 0 {
        // one array exists: the empty array
        return vec![vec![]];
    }
    if trues == 0 {
        // one array exists: the all-false array
        return vec![vec![false; length as usize]];
    }

    let mut result = Vec::new();
    for mut ones in solution(length-1, trues-1) {
        ones.push(true);
        result.push(ones);
    }
    for mut zeroes in solution(length-1, trues) {
        zeroes.push(false);
        result.push(zeroes);
    }
    result
}
```

If the time complexity for `solution(L, T)` is `O(S(L,T))`, then the time complexity of `solution(L,T)` can be recursively expressed as `O(S(L-1,T-1) + S(L-1,T))`, with the base cases `S(0,0) = 1`, `S(L,L+1)=1`, `S(L,0) = L`. This is the best achievable time complexity, since `S(L,T) = S(L-1,T-1) + S(L-1,T)` is also the recursive formula for how many arrays of length L and true-count T exist. This is also the same recurrence formula as the [binomial recurrence equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), but the base cases are different. I will leave computing the time complexity as an exercise to the reader, and there are a couple of trivial optimizations to the above code that can be done to bring down the computation time further.